# ALSA - setting input volume for line in command line - input not recognized but available for programs

Tags: input, volume, alsa

I cant see the input device in alsamixer on the usb board, but it is listed as I do arecord -L (also why is it listing the 2nd sound card by default ?)

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I can see many informations but I cant figure from man, how to change the level of the line input in command line nor in the gui

```
 amixer info 
Card default 'CODEC'/'Burr-Brown from TI USB Audio CODEC at usb-3f980000.usb-1.3, full speed'
  Mixer name    : 'USB Mixer'
  Components    : 'USB08bb:2902'
  Controls      : 4
  Simple ctrls  : 1

amixer contents
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=128,step=0
  : values=128,128
  | dBminmax-min=-128.00dB,max=0.00dB
numid=2,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
    | chmap-fixed=MONO

numid=1,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
    | chmap-fixed=MONO
```

I am actualy not sure about how to achieve this since many people say thousands of different thing

here I try to set the volume in a clumsy way, and it does not work :

```
amixer  -c 1 sset numid=2 0
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'numid=2',0

amixer  -c 1 cset numid=2 0
amixer: Control hw:1 element write error: Operation not permitted

sudo amixer  -c 1 cset numid=2 0
amixer: Control hw:1 element write error: Operation not permitted
```

amixer does not list any record device although I can clearly record audio with audacity or puredata

```
amixer -c 1
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 128
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 128 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 128 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]

amixer -c 0
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback 0 [96%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

please help me out, this makes no sens at all to me

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

`amixer` and `alsamixer` shows those mixer controls that the hardware actually has.

As figure 31 in the [PCM2902 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/PCM2902) shows, this device indeed has no mechanism to change the capture volume:

[image: PCM2902 USB Audio Function Topology]

It might be possible to add a `softvol` plugin, but it would be easier to just use PulseAudio.

Comment: even with pulseaudio, I dont get any level setting on the input